# Unable to set Page margin in flying-saucer

Tags: java, pdf, jsoup, flying-saucer

I am generating pdf from html. I am using dynamic html generator(`Apache-velocity`) and using `jsoup` for html parsing. I generate pdf successfully, issue is `html` content not aligned properly in `pdf` after generation. I already visited this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280995/itextrenderer-adjust-page-height-to-content) unluckily its unanswered.

Comment: Your question seems to be about Flying Saucer, not about iText.

Comment: sorry for that.

Comment: Can you show the HTML used to generated the PDF, and explain what you mean by "not aligned properly" ?

Comment: I am having sample pdf consist 3 pages.I converted it into `html` and I am generating pdf using that html file. Issue is generated pdf contains 4 pages.I am having 2 tables in html which are not aligned properly in pdf, like row of the table separately printed in different pages.I used`@page {
                margin-left: 1cm;
                margin-right: 1cm;
                }
                tr{
                page-break-inside:avoid;
                }`  in my html but it cheats me

Answer (score 1):

Margin can be set in html in head tag using style tag. Sample for adding 1px margin is shown. In my case for flying saucer library it worked well with this.

```html
<head><style>@page {size: Wpx 1px;margin:0px;}<style/><head/>
```